# Heap memory access in lua

Tags: lua, heap-memory

Is it possible to access contents of heap memory  in Lua by passing it a pointer to memory address allocated by `malloc` function in C?

I have tried this :

```
int *j=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
j[0]=5;
```

passing (`j` as a pointer to Lua), then Lua access contents at memory location pointed by pointer `j`.

Comment: Why do you want or need to do that?

Comment: Because I want to write two modules  1 : That Capture IP Packets in 'c' language in the required "Structure" format and allocate memory using malloc and pass pointer to that structure to lua through stack shared between lua and c and 2:Lua module that reads that packet and process it.

Comment: You may simply use strings or tables for that then. Strings in Lua an contain arbitrary binary data.

Comment: But Can't heap be treated as shared memory between two processes and is it not possible through shared memory concept , to share memory between two processes, in such a way that one process produces data and another one consumes it. "C" producer and lua "Consumer" .

Comment: No, two separate *processes* do *not* share any memory in modern operating systems. This is what *shared memory* (google it) is for

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in support for that.

You can write your own support in C by exporting a version of `malloc` to Lua that creates memory buffers as userdata and provides suitable metamethods for easy access of the contents. (But use `lua_newuserdata` instead `malloc`.)

A few of these have appeared in the Lua mailing list. See for instance

- *bytes* at http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-06/msg00114.html
- *lbuffer* at http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-10/msg00209.html

Comment: But Can't heap be treated as shared memory between two processes and is it not possible through shared memory concept , to share memory between two processes, in such a way that one process produces data and another one consumes it.                                                                 "C" producer and lua "Consumer" .

Comment: @user2589882 Whether heap memory can be shared between two processes really has nothing to do with lua per-say. To share memory between two *different processes* you have to use the provided system API which is clearly OS & platform dependent or some kind of IPC. Of course you can create bindings for them so it's accessible to lua.

Answer (score 1):

What do you actually want to do? Your question seems to ask about moving data from C to Lua. Your comments suggest that you want to share memory between two separate processes.

If you just want to use some C with Lua, then you should write and extension (and use [userdata](http://www.lua.org/pil/28.1.html) to move data around). For example, if you have a library written in C and you want to use it in Lua, you will need to extend Lua with a module wrapping the library. This is covered in [Part IV of PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.html). When using an extension, there is only one process so memory is easily shared between C and Lua.

If you really need to share data between two processes, you will need to find some kind of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) that works for you. Using a socket is an obvious choice, for that you can use [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/). If you want a pub/sub, then you could try [LCM](https://code.google.com/p/lcm/), which supports both C and Lua.